# xfce4 terminal changes geometry when a new tab is opened

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, xfce4-terminal

Using XUbuntu 18.10 (but suspect same behaviour on earlier versions, now that I've noticed it!):

Open a terminal - default geometry is 80x24 as expected.

In that terminal, open a new tab (ctl-shift-T). Now geometry on both original terminals is maybe 96x24, sometimes 97x24! (As reported by 'tput cols' and/or echo $COLUMNS)

How can I get it to remain at 80xYY rather than 96xYY?

(Yes, have looked at the documentation, in ~/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc
 and in /etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc, in the Preferences settings, etc!)

Comment: With Xubuntu 18.04, although opening a new tab in xfce4-terminal increases the overall size of the window to accommodate the row containing the tabs, the "data" area remains unchanged at 80x24. • PS: 18.10 will not be supported after July 18, 2019!

Comment: Hmm, OK, Just double checked what I was doing:

- if I just open terminal, then open new tab, you are correct

- if I open terminal, then ctl-shift-+ to increase size of text (at this point 'tput cols' is 80) and **then** ctl-shift-T to add a tab, now 'tput cols' is 96 or 97....

(And yip, aware of the release/support schedule, thanks - just haven't quite got to 19.04 on the machine I have here!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is an up-stream bug in xfce4-terminal: https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15785